# Datagridview Combobox and Textbox event not firing when data is loading

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I am creating an application in which datagridview having one combobox and multiple textbox

In datagridview, when I select manually datagridviewcombobox value, Textbox value is filled

But datagridview is populated by bindingsource and value of datagridviewcombobox get selected but textbox value is empty

**Example as below**

Combobox value selected by user, Account Name textbox filled
[image]

Combobox value selected by bindingsource(Dynamically), Account Name textbox is Empty

[image]

**Below is my code**

```
int journalID = 0;
public Add(int id = 0)
{
     BindControls();
     journalID = id;
}


  private async void BindControls()
  {
     try
     {               
            if (journalID > 0)
            {
                List<JournalAccountViewModel> list = await new JournalModel().GetDetailById(journalID);
                for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    bindingSource1.Add(list[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bindingSource1.Add(new JournalAccountViewModel());
                bindingSource1.List.Clear();
            }
            dgvJournal.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvJournal.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            dgvJournal.AutoSize = true;
            dgvJournal.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Rule", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


   private void dgvJournal_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dgvJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dgvJournal.Columns[colCredit.Name].Index) //Desired Column
            {
                TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtNumeri_KeyPress);
                }
            }

            if (dgvJournal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dgvJournal.Columns[ColDebit.Name].Index) //Desired Column
            {
                TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtNumeri_KeyPress);
                }
            }


            ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (combo != null)
            {
                combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
                combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Rule", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }


   private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem != null)
            {
                AccountViewModel account = (AccountViewModel)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
                var currentcell = dgvJournal.CurrentCellAddress;
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dgvJournal.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[ColAccountName.Name];
                cel.Value = account.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Rule", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

  private void txtNumeri_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            // only allow one decimal point
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Rule", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me how to get textbox value filled when combobox value is set programmtically.

Comment: @JohnG DataGridViewComboBox do  have a SelectedIndexChanged event which can be called in EditingControlShowing .I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void dgvJournal_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset)
        {
            var a = (DataGridView)sender;
            var b = a.DataSource;
            var c = (BindingSource)b;
            var d = c.List;
            int sumDebit = 0, sumCredit = 0;
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (JournalAccountViewModel account in d)
            {
                dgvJournal.Rows[cnt].Cells[ColAccountName.Name].Value = accountList.Where(acc => acc.ID == account.AccountID).FirstOrDefault().Name;
                enableCell(((DataGridViewCell)dgvJournal.Rows[cnt].Cells[ColDebit.Name]), (account.Debit > 0));
                enableCell(((DataGridViewCell)dgvJournal.Rows[cnt].Cells[colCredit.Name]), (account.Credit > 0));
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a *CellValueChanged* event for that DataGridView and copy over the functionality from your *ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged* event. This would eliminate the need to set those events in *dgvJournal_EditingControlShowing* and also resolve your original issue since it will fire anytime a value is changed in the *AccountNumber* field.

```
    private void dgvJournal_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int accountNumberColIndex = dgvJournal.Columns["AccountNumber"].Index;

        // Checking that this value is from the account number column
        if (e.ColumnIndex == accountNumberColIndex)
        {
            AccountViewModel account = (AccountViewModel) dgvJournal.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            int accountNameColIndex = dgvJournal.Columns["AccountName"].Index;

            DataGridViewTextBoxCell accountNameCell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell) dgvJournal.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[accountNameColIndex];
            accountNameCell.Value = account.Name;
        }
    }
```